# Kite Dataset map-reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I am trying to do map-reduce with kite-dataset api.

I have followed below urls to refer.

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Kite-SDK-includes-Morphlines/Map-Reduce-with-Kite/td-p/22165

https://github.com/kite-sdk/kite/blob/master/kite-data/kite-data-mapreduce/src/test/java/org/kitesdk/data/mapreduce/TestMapReduce.java

My code snippet as below

```
public class MapReduce {

    private static final String sourceDatasetURI = "dataset:hive:test_avro";

    private static final String destinationDatasetURI = "dataset:hive:test_parquet";

    private static class LineCountMapper
            extends Mapper<GenericData.Record, Void, Text, IntWritable> {
        @Override
        protected void map(GenericData.Record record, Void value,
                           Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("Record is "+record);
            context.write(new Text(record.get("index").toString()), new IntWritable(1));
        }
    }

    private Job createJob() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside Create Job");
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(getClass());

       Dataset<GenericData.Record> inputDataset = Datasets.load(sourceDatasetURI, GenericData.Record.class);
       Dataset<GenericData.Record> outputDataset = Datasets.load(destinationDatasetURI, GenericData.Record.class);

        DatasetKeyInputFormat.configure(job).readFrom(inputDataset).withType(GenericData.Record.class);

        job.setMapperClass(LineCountMapper.class);
        DatasetKeyOutputFormat.configure(job).writeTo(outputDataset).withType(GenericData.Record.class);

        job.waitForCompletion(true);

        return job;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MapReduce httAvroToParquet = new MapReduce();
        httAvroToParquet.createJob();
    }
}
```

I am using HDP 2.3.2 box ,creating assembly jar and submitting my application through spark-submit.

I am getting below error when I submit my application.

```
2015-12-18 04:09:07,156 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
2015-12-18 04:09:07,282 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: OutputCommitter set in config null
2015-12-18 04:09:07,333 WARN [main] org.kitesdk.data.spi.Registration: Not loading URI patterns in org.kitesdk.data.spi.hive.Loader
2015-12-18 04:09:07,334 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster failed in state INITED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: org.kitesdk.data.DatasetNotFoundException: Unknown dataset URI: hive://{}:9083/default/test_parquet. Check that JARs for hive datasets are on the classpath.
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: org.kitesdk.data.DatasetNotFoundException: Unknown dataset URI: hive://{}:9083/default/test_parquet. Check that JARs for hive datasets are on the classpath.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.callWithJobClassLoader(MRAppMaster.java:1560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.createOutputCommitter(MRAppMaster.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$4.run(MRAppMaster.java:1518)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1448)
Caused by: org.kitesdk.data.DatasetNotFoundException: Unknown dataset URI: hive://{}:9083/default/test_parquet. Check that JARs for hive datasets are on the classpath.
    at org.kitesdk.data.spi.Registration.lookupDatasetUri(Registration.java:109)
    at org.kitesdk.data.Datasets.load(Datasets.java:103)
    at org.kitesdk.data.Datasets.load(Datasets.java:165)
    at org.kitesdk.data.mapreduce.DatasetKeyOutputFormat.load(DatasetKeyOutputFormat.java:510)
    at org.kitesdk.data.mapreduce.DatasetKeyOutputFormat.getOutputCommitter(DatasetKeyOutputFormat.java:473)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:476)
    ... 11 more
```

I am not getting what's wrong ? Is there any class-path problem ? If yes then where do I set it ?

Answer (score 0):

You effectively have a classpath problem

Your project is missing org.kitesdk:kite-data-hive

You can

- Add this jar to your fat jar before submitting it to Spark
- Tells Spark to add it to your classpath when you submit